# Java JPanel expand one panel in BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, border-layout

I have two simple JPanels, one positioned on top and the other on the bottom.

Now im trying to resize the top panel to take up more space (and therefore push the bottom panel down)

Ive added a button where i listen on call like:

```
  button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {  
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {   
          panelTop.setSize(10, 200);
      }  
  });
```

This is how i add my panels:

```
add(panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(panelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Any ideas if this is possible?

My tests are not working at all

Comment: What is in these panels?  Explain in the form of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  I feel the current answers, while correct, are less than optimal.  Will know more when I see the SSCCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `setPreferredSize` instead of `setSize`. The `BorderLayout` will notice this and resize the panel on the next `validate()`.

Comment: Some good reason to override `etPreferredSize()` are suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to do can be easily solved with a [`JSplitPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html)

This will take two components and put a divider between the two that you can use to re-size them.